# join two files based on two columns

Tags: bash, awk

Believe it or not, I've searched all over the internet and haven't found a working solution for this problem in AWK.

I have two files, A and B:

File A:

```
chr1   pos1   
chr1   pos2
chr2   pos1
chr2   pos2
```

File B:

```
chr1 pos1
chr2 pos1
chr3 pos2
```

Desired Output:

```
chr1 pos1
chr2 pos1
```

I'd like to join these two files to basically get the intersection between the two files based on the first AND second columns, not just the first. Since this is the case, most simple scripts won't work and join doesn't seem to be an option.

Any ideas?

EDIT: sorry, I didn't mention that there are more columns than just the two I showed. I've only shown two in my example because I'm only interested in the first two columns between both files being identical, the rest of the data aren't important (but are nonetheless in the file)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hum, my idea is the following:
Use `join` to merge the two files and correct with awk

```
$ join  A B 
chr1 pos1 pos1
chr1 pos2 pos1
chr2 pos1 pos1
chr2 pos2 pos1

$ join  A B | awk '{ if ($2==$3) printf("%s %s\n", $1, $2) }'
chr1 pos1 pos1
chr2 pos1 pos1
```

Edit: given the edit, the join solution may still work (with options), so the concept remains correct (imo).

Comment: Why not: `join  A B | awk '{ if ($2==$3) print $0 }' | awk '{ print $1 " " $2 }'` so he has the correct output?

Comment: I add corrected my answer to behave as wanted. The printf is better than piping an other awk imo.

Comment: Note that `join` requires sorted input. This may or may not be an obstacle.

Comment: At least with GNU coreutils join, you can specify which columns to print, so the awk may be unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

The awk solution is:

```
awk 'FILENAME==ARGV[1] {pair[$1 " " $2]; next} ($1 " " $2 in pair)' fileB fileA
```

Place the smaller file first since you have to basically hold it in memory.

Comment: very nice way to use `FILENAME==ARVG[1]`. This has the advantage over `NR==FNR` that empty files are handled correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I would write it like this:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {
  k[$1, $2]
  next
  }
($1, $2) in k
  ' filea fileb
```

The order of the input files might need to be adapted based on the exact requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simple `grep -f` like this:

```
grep -f fileB fileA
```

#### EDIT:

For files having more than 2 columns try this:

```
grep "$(cut -d" " -f1,2 fileB)" fileA | cut -d" " -f1,2
```

Comment: Your edit should be `grep -f <(cut -d " " -f 1,2 fileB) fileA | ...` -- that cut command will return several lines which you want to treat as a file, not as a single string.

Comment: Also, `grep -f` assumes the spacing between columns is the same in both files, but the example shown does not display that.