# exiting an IF statement after initial match bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix, if-statement, scripting

I have a script which iterates through a file and finds matches in another file. How to I get the process to stop once I've found a match.

For example:
I take the first line in name.txt, and then try to find a match for it in file.txt.

name.txt:

```
 7,7,FRESH,98,135,
 65,10,OLD,56,45,
```

file.txt:

```
 7,7,Dave,S
 8,10,Frank,S
 31,7,Gregg
 45,5,Jake,S
```

Script:

```
while read line
do

    name_id=`echo $line | cut -f1,2 -d ','`
    identiferOne=`echo $name_id | cut -f1 -d ','`
    identiferTwo=`echo $name_id | cut -f2 -d ','`


    while IFS= read line
    do
        CHECK=`echo $line | cut -f4 -d','`
        if [ $CHECK = "S" ]
        then
            symbolName=`echo $line | cut -f3 -d ','`
            numberOne=`echo $line | awk -F',' '{print $1}'`
            numberTwo=`echo $line | cut -f2 -d ','`

            if [ "$numberOne" == $identiferOne ] && [ "$numberTwo" == $identifierTwo ]
            then
                echo "WE HAVE A MATCH with $symbolName"
                break
            fi
        fi

    done < /tmp/file.txt

done < /tmp/name.txt
```

My question is - how do I stop the script from iterating through file.txt once it has found an initial match, and then set that matched record into a variable, stop the if statement, then do some other stuff within the loop using that variable. I tried using `break;` but that exits the loop, which is not what I want.

Comment: If you don't want it to exit the loop but you want it to stop processing lines (which is exactly what the loop is doing), isn't that a contradiction? What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: @user3035772 I want the if statement to cease after its first successful match.

Comment: That is what you have right now. I don't understand the question. Currently your if statement should make it say "WE HAVE A MATCH" (I assume you're going to put more code there), then the `break` will cause it to stop scanning `file.txt` for that specific `name_id`, and go fetch a new `name_id` from `name.txt` instead. That sounds like exactly what you're asking for and you have it in your code already, so what needs to be different?

Comment: By the way, this command might interest you: `join -t , -j 1 -o 1.1,1.2,2.2,1.3,2.3 <(sort -t, name.txt) <(sort -t, file.txt) | awk -F, '$2==$3 { print $4, $5 }'` -- if so this question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392204/join-two-files-based-on-two-columns

Comment: @user3035772 I want the if statement to cease after its first successful match then do something (run some commands) with the `$symbolName`. If it does not exit the if statement then it will "do something / run commands" for EVERY match it finds in file.txt, which is not what i want. I just want to do something with the FIRST match of the if statement, THEN exit the loop and grab the new name_id.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what you're doing right now with the `break`. The `break` exits the `file.txt` loop, but does not exit the `name.txt` loop. So if you put your "do something/run commands" before the `break`, it should be exactly what you want.

Comment: If you wish to exit the outer loop from the inner loop then (in this case) use `break 2`.  The `2` is the nesting level you wish to break (default is 1).  However that could be considered poor design.

Comment: @user3035772 It doesnt do that though, it displays the match. Then the `break` seems to stop the script as a whole, instead of grabbing a new name_id.

Comment: Do not use the same variable name `line` in the inner and outer loop.

Comment: @nrs90 Well, in your example files you don't have more than one line which would match.

Comment: @WalterA that is irrelevant, because it won't change anything

Answer (score 0):

You can tell grep different things:
Stop searching after the first match (option `-m 1`).
Read the searchkeys from a file (option `-f file`).
Pretend that the output of a command is a file (not really grep, bash helps here) with `<(cmmnd)`.

Combining these will give you

```
grep -m1 -f <(cut -d"," -f1-2 name.txt) file.txt
```

Close, but not what you want. The substrings given by `cut -d","  -f1-2 name.txt` will match everywhere in the line, and you want to match the first two fields. Matching at the start of the line is done with `^`, so we use sed to make strings like `^field1,field2` :

```
grep -m1 -f <(sed 's/\([^,]*,[^,]*,\).*/^\1/' name.txt) file.txt
```