# How to join two huge files based on the first two columns in awk/Bash programs?

Tags: bash, awk

There are multiple threads explaining [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392204/join-two-files-based-on-two-columns) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210503/join-on-first-column-of-two-files) on how to perform merging between two files using `awk` for example.

My problem is a bit more complicated since my files are very huge. `file1.tsv` is 288gb and 109 columns and `file2.tsv` is 16gb with 4 columns. I would like to join these files based on the first two columns:

`file1.tsv` (tab-separated) with 109 columns (here showing first 4 and last column):

```
CHROM   POS     REF     ALT ... FILTER
chr1    10031   T       C   ... AC0;AS_VQSR
chr1    10037   T       C   ... AS_VQSR
chr1    10040   T       A   ... PASS
chr1    10043   T       C   ... AS_VQSR
chr1    10055   T       C   ... AS_VQSR
chr1    10057   A       C   ... AC0
```

`file2.tsv` (tab-separated) with 4 columns:

```
CHROM   POS     CHROM_hg19  POS_hg19
chr1    10031   chr1        10034
chr1    10037   chr1        10042
chr1    10043   chr1        10084
chr1    10055   chr1        10253
chr1    10057   chr1        10434
```

I wish to add the two last columns from `file2.tsv` to `file1.tsv` by matching on `CHROM` and `POS` while keeping all non-matching rows from `file1.txt`:

`file3.txt`

```
CHROM   POS     REF     ALT ... FILTER        CHROM_hg19    POS_hg19
chr1    10031   T       C   ... AC0;AS_VQSR   chr1          10034
chr1    10037   T       C   ... AS_VQSR       chr1          10042
chr1    10040   T       A   ... PASS          -             -
chr1    10043   T       C   ... AS_VQSR       chr1          10084
chr1    10055   T       C   ... AS_VQSR       chr1          10253
chr1    10057   A       C   ... AC0           chr1          10434
```

But as you have figured, these files are big. I tried the following:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next} ($1,$2) in a{print $0, a[$1,$2]}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

And as soon as I hit enter, I saw my memory rocketing and no results being produced. I am unsure if this will produce the correct results at the end or how much memory it will use. Is there a better way to join my files in any methods using `awk` or any `Bash` programs?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question feels like it needs a database to resolve. It's trivial if SQL can be used with proper indexing and optimization available in the engine. Is this a one time need or ongoing? Do you have someone with database experience?

Comment: Are the values in the `POS` column always in increasing sort order? That may allow an incremental read though `file1.tsv` reading a line from `file2.tsv` and then processing records in `file1.tsv` until the matching `POS` from `file2.tsv` is reaches and the last two columns added. `getline()` will allow this, but you would want to preserve the file position in `file2.tsv` between calls to `getline()` to make this reasonably efficient.

Comment: @DavidMedinets I have knowledge with the database. I can probably do that with `MySQL`, `MongoDB` or `R` by reading `file1.tsv` by chunks. I was looking to do with a Bash way instead since it will help ease my developments.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I believe they do but once it switches to a new `CHROM`, the `POS` starts over again from a lower value. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: As long as the pair of the first two columns maintain that sort order, that would be doable. The reason I would look at this approach is it does not require storing either file in memory, but instead reading from file2 and then scanning forward in file1 outputting lines unchanged until the matching information from file2 needs to be appended. Append the file2 columns read the next line from file2 and repeat until you run out of lines.

Comment: Swap file1.txt and file2.txt in your command.

Comment: @Cyrus alright, I will try that too !

Comment: Last thought, rather than bash, awk, etc.. Since the file sizes are huge, why not a short C program that opens both files and implements the logic explained above? That would take less than 50 lines or so and would optimize to about as efficient as possible. The `join` solution may work just fine, I don't have a feel for how efficient it will be, it looks really good, but if that runs into problems, you may want to consider a short compiled special purpose bit of code here as well..

Comment: In your example, you parse the files in the wrong order. Assuming this is the command you really tried, besides it would not output what you want, file1 is 288gb and would not fit to memory. You want this command: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3,$4;next} ($1,$2) in a{print $0, a[$1,$2]}' file2.txt file1.txt`. I guess it will need a bit more than 16gb of memory. If you have not that memory, or this was just a typo in your description, another workaround is to split file2 to a few parts, and run above command a few times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `join`, `sed` and `bash` (Process Substitution):

```
join -t $'\t' -a 1 <(sed 's/\t/:/' file1.tsv) <(sed 's/\t/:/' file2.tsv) | sed 's/:/\t/' > file3.txt
```

This solution assumes that the first two columns are sorted together in ascending order in both files.

---

See: `man join`

Comment: Thanks for the proposed answer. I will try it out tomorrow and come back with the news.

Comment: I really like this `join` approach but I am confused with the decorate with `':'` to join and then undecorate to restore the `'\t'` separators in the output. This should work beautifully since `join` will be able to process lines as they are read from each of the process substitutions, but why can't you just omit `sed` and redirect from the tsv files themselves?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: In this way I try to merge the first two columns for `join` into one. Another solution is not known to me with `join`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Thanks for the question. It shows me that I should have explained how my solution works.

Comment: Nice solution! If you replace the `sed 's/:/\t/'` at the end with `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {sub(/:/,FS)} NR==1{nf=NF} {for (i=NF+1;i<=nf;i++) $i="-"; print}'` then it'll add the desired `-`s for the missing fields at the end of the `chr1    10040` line (or others with no matches in file2.tsv)

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes, this is a good catch. I had missed that. I just found out that with GNU join `-e "-" -o auto` is also possible.

Comment: I have a question for this command. Please look at my edited OP for the example. Does still works in that case ?

Comment: @Zen: Please do not expand your question if someone has already answered. I recommend to ask a new question.

Comment: @Cyrus congratulations, you have been awarded the chameleon hunter badge.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails you could brute-force it and read a line from file1 then read lines from file2 until you hit a match or higher number, then read the next line from file1, etc. The advantage to that approach is that very little is being stored in memory so it should work no matter how large your files are.

This isn't quite right but I don't have any more time to think about it so consider it a start and if anyone wants to finish it off and post the finished product as an answer, be my guest:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    f1name = ARGV[1]
    f2name = ARGV[2]
    ARGV[1] = ARGV[2] = ""
    while ( !done ) {
        if ( (f1stat = (getline line1 < f1name)) > 0 ) {
            split(line1,f1)
            f1key = f1[1] FS f1[2]
        }

        matched = 0
        while ( !eof && !matched ) {
            if ( (f2stat = (getline line2 < f2name)) > 0 ) {
                split(line2,f2)
                f2key = f2[1] FS f2[2]
                matched = (f1key == f2key)
            }
            else {
                eof = 1
            }
        }

        print line1, (matched ? f2[3] OFS f2[4] : "-" OFS "-")

        if ( (f1stat <= 0) && (f2stat <= 0) ) {
            done = 1
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1.tsv file2.tsv
CHROM   POS     REF     ALT     ...     FILTER CHROM_hg19 POS_hg19
chr1    10031   T       C       ...     AC0;AS_VQSR chr1 10034
chr1    10037   T       C       ...     AS_VQSR chr1 10042
chr1    10040   T       A       ...     PASS - -
chr1    10043   T       C       ...     AS_VQSR - -
chr1    10055   T       C       ...     AS_VQSR - -
chr1    10057   A       C       ...     AC0 - -
chr1    10057   A       C       ...     AC0 - -
```